# Juniper, vlan-centric vs interface-centric. Which has prevalence?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I am new to Juniper and has a basic doubt about assigning an interface to a VLAN. I have read that JunOS admits both approaches. My question is, what method prevalence when you use **both** of them?

I mean, I have encountered this real config in a device:

```
xe-5/1/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ v20 v30 ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
....
vlans {
    v40 {
        description OTHERVLAN;
        vlan-id 40;
        interface {
            xe-0/1/0.0;
            xe-5/1/0.0;
        }
    }
    v50 {
        description v50;
        vlan-id 50;
        interface {
            xe-0/1/0.0;
            xe-5/1/0.0;
        }
...
```

In this case, what Vlan IDs are being transmitted by interface xe-5/1/0.0, v20 and v30? v40 and v50? all of them?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not around a switch right now, but you will be able to see what those interfaces are tagging with `show ethernet-switching interfaces xe-5/1/0`.

Comment: It's worked. Seems that both configs are compatible because 4 vlans are being transmitted.

Comment: hm, junipers are nice ;-) cisco cant do vlan-centric, imho it can seriously reduce config length in access switches at least...) curious, there no "trunk mode" commands in vlan-centric config, so port became trunked when was "used" for more than 1 vlan? if yes, which one vlan will be untagged(native), first?

Comment: Pyatka - Junos does not have a default native vlan. Native vlan must be configured separately via 'native-vlan-id' statement. One thing of note is that if a vlan is explicitly added as a trunk port member that vlan becomes tagged even if it is explicitly configured as the native vlan. There are a few docs explaining this behaviour from Juniper.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't juniper switches(only ns25 fw, at home collection), asked this just for curious )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ryan suggests, I use show ethernet-switching interfaces xe-5/1/0 to show what VLAN id are being transported.

According to this info, the 4 VLANs are being transported. So VLAN-centric and interface-centric are compatible.